# Wie kann man wissen, welches "da-" Wort in einem Nebensatz zu verwenden ist?

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Z.b:

> Ich habe **darüber** nachgedacht, ob ich mir einen neuen Wagen zulegen sollte.

> Ich bin **davon** überzeugt, dass meine Tochter die Prüfung bestehen wird.

> Danke **dafür**, dass Sie mich benachrichtigt haben.

Gibt es eine Regel für diese Beispiele? Oder ist es so, dass diese Wörter die spezifischen Präpositionen nehmen? Das dritte Beispiel verwirrt mich am meisten.

Comment: Nur zur Formulierung der Überschrift: Das „da“-Wort ist im Hauptsatz, der Nebensatz bezieht sich darauf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diese mit "da"-Wörtern eingeleiteten Sätze entsprechen alle feststehenden Wendungen. Von diesen Wendungen sind die jeweiligen "da-"Wörter bezogen:

> Ich habe darüber nachgedacht ("nachdenken über")
> Ich bin davon überzeugt ("überzeugt sein von")
> Danke dafür ("danken für")

Dasselbe gilt übrigens auch für "wo"-Wörter:

> Q: Worüber hast du nachgedacht?
> A: Darüber habe ich nachgedacht!

Dein letztes Beispiel fällt tatsächlich ein wenig aus der Reihe, weil das "danke" hier keine "übliche" Verbform darstellt.

Die "Regel" lautet etwa: finde die feststehende Wendung und mache aus der jeweiligen Präposition das entsprechende "da"-Wort (oder, bei Fragen, "wo-"Wort):

> hantieren mit - damit hantieren
> reden über - darüber reden
> lassen von - davon lassen

---

Kurze (naja) Nachbemerkung über die Motivation der "da"-Wörter:

Es gibt eine Klasse von Wörtern, die Nomina vertreten können - Pronomina. Das z.B. geht zwar:

> Ich habe ein *Fahrrad* und möchte mit dem *Fahrrad* fahren.

aber klingt unbeholfen. Flüssiger ist das:

> Ich habe ein *Fahrrad* und möchte mit *ihm* fahren.

Das ist logisch, weil "ihm" der Dativ von "es" ist und "mit" ebendiesen Dativ verlangt. Aber es geht noch besser:

> Ich habe ein *Fahrrad* und möchte *damit* fahren.

Ich weiß nicht, ob das wirklich eine "Regel" ist, aber zumindest fällt mir kein Gegenbeipiel ein - die Regel geht so:

> Wenn Du einen Satz hast, in dem ein "es" als Pronomen auftaucht und mit einer Präposition verbunden wird, dann kann man die beiden auch durch ein "da"-Wort (nämlich "da + Präposition") ersetzen.

Im obigen Beispiel wäre das "ihm" (der Dativ von "es") und "mit", das durch "damit" ersetzt wird. Beachte, daß das nur mit unbelebten Dingen geht (deshalb zwar "es" und seine Formen, aber nicht "er" oder "sie" und deren Formen):

> Ich träume vom Sommer. Ich träume *davon*. (korrekt)
> Ich träume von meiner Mutter. Ich träume davon. (FALSCH)

Eine andere Funktion der "da"-Wörter (und nicht nur der) ist, als Platzhalter eines Nebensatzes zu fungieren. Bestimmte Verben verlangen ein Objekt, nehmen wir als Beispiel "warten":

> Ich warte *auf etwas*.

Dieses "etwas" kann aber etwas sein, das sich nicht in einem Wort (und deshalb im Hauptsatz) ausdrücken läßt. z.B.:

> Ich warte - *daß diese Antwort endlich zu einem Ende kommt*.

Das Objekt des Wartens ist damit klar, aber im Hauptsatz ("Ich warte auf [Objekt]") fehlt nun was. Dort muß etwas hin, das anzeigt, daß dieses Objekt im Nebensatz "nachgeliefert" wird:

> Ich warte *darauf*, daß diese Antwort endlich zu einem Ende kommt.

Solche Platzhalter nennt man "Korrelat" und sie dienen dazu, anzuzeigen, daß ein (vorheriger oder folgender) Nebensatz kommt, der ein Objekt vertritt:

> Das Trinken von 3 Liter Wasser täglich ist gesund.
> *Es* ist gesund, 3 Liter Wasser täglich zu trinken.

Da "es" vertritt hier den folgenden Nebensatz. Das geht auch umgekehrt, der Nebensatz kommt zuerst und im nachfolgenden Hauptsatz wird der Platz, den er eigentlich einnimmt, durch ein Korrelat markiert:

> Daß ich einmal im Lotto gewinne, *darauf* habe ich gewartet.

Auch hier gilt, wie überall im Deutschen, daß die Anordnung der Objekte hauptsächlich der Betonung dient. Daß der Nebensatz an erster steht, hebt ihn hervor. Das:

> Ich habe *darauf* gewartet, daß ich einmal im Lotto gewinne.

ist zwar korrekt, aber der Grund meines Wartens wird nicht so stark betont.

Comment: Könnte das Problem für den Fragesteller die Korrelat-Funktion des da-Wortes sein?

Comment: @Alazon: ich habe versucht, das durch den Nachtrag sozusagen "durch die Hintertür" zu erläutern.